# Is there a place for feature requests or for noting discrepancies in the geocoding search results?

Tags: here-api

Just let me know if there is anything I can do or I caused this mistake.

I am using the Geocoding API for Javascript:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.15.1/dev_guide/topics/geocoding.html
and it's working good so far.

My problem are the results:

-If I search for Eiffel Tower or Golden Gate Bridge, I actually do get a match/suggestion. But if I search for CN Tower (prominent Canadian/Torontonian tourist spot) it shows no results. In the same HERE maps url above, it indicates that you can search by addresses, certain localities,  and even famous landmarks (deemed nationally important). I think CN tower qualifies.

-The other is if I try to search for "Bali" (as in Bali, Indonesia).
If I type "Bali", it shows Paris (whut). I'll give it the benefit of the doubt and maybe the algo is thinking this is a typo: Bali > Bari > Pari > Paris. I can let that slide. Although, how come Bali, Indonesia is not a second or third suggestion?
[image]

If I further complete the query:
[image]

Ok, makes sense, but how come this didn't show above as a second/third option, same with the actual Bali, Indonesia.

[image]

same concerns...

[image]

At last! But at this point it's useless to suggest something I've completed already, also, as a non-coder, just-a-consumer visitor, if I type: "b-a-l-i-,-i-n-d-o" and "Bali, Indonesia" still does not show, I probably would just assume that that location is not recognized/supported in the API and I'd give up.

Is there something I can do to optimize it or if this is strictly algo, is there any place I can submit this to the HERE Maps developers so I can help them improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoder is not meant to search for places in general. However it is able to find some important places via the landmark geocode resource:

In General, better is to use search
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=47.427%2C-84.4889&q=CN+Tower+toronto&threshold=true&size=50&X-Mobility-Mode=drive&Accept-Language=en-US&app_id=7xKgcpva59oPCkQw7yWW&app_code=L8fBMv68cNVnA2Kf2QA8KQ

For Bali: Geocoder is build to find the best fine granular match. Bali returns 3 cities, whereas the Bali, IDN is a county. A general search for Bali with specifying the country will return the city matches as best results. You have to add the country to narrow down the search.